# After "dismissing" UIWindow, cursor on search list is missing

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, cursor, uiwindow

I created a custom UIWindow, UIViewController, and UIView in order to present a full-screen overlay for various screens through an app. Display, rotation, and dismissing the overlay works great.

However, the problem is that after dismissing the custom UIWindow, a search box on one of my underlying views does not have the blinking blue cursor. The keyboard appears and I can enter characters into the search box, but no cursor.

The other strange thing is that the cursor appears as expected on the iOS simulator, but not on a device.

Anyone have any ideas what's going on here? I've already tried traversing down my overlay view hierarchy to make sure all views ResignFirstResponder(). Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. At the time that I was trying to grab a reference to my original UIWindow, a couple extra UIWindows were present. I used the KeyWindow property to try to get at my original window. But, KeyWindow was not the UIWindow I expected it to be. I had a loading spinner active, so the window was of type _UIAlertNormalizingOverlayWindow. So, now I'm calling the 0 index of the Windows array instead which DOES get my main application window. Then I was able to call MakeKeyAndVisible on the correct UIWindow.

For some reason, calling MakeKeyAndVisible on the wrong window caused some weirdness that appeared to hide the UITextEffectsWindow, which is the window type that iOS uses to display cursors in text fields and such.

So, my learned lesson is: never assume which instance of the windows array that you will get when accessing the KeyWindow property.